# React props not loaded in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, how do I do something if this.props have been loaded?? I tried componentDidUpdate to check to see if @props are different to prevProps but I found that they are always the same thing :-/

I want to call the function below when @props.account.subbableProperties is not blank.

```
uiActions.curliesPropertyReplacement
  element: @textarea
  words: @props.account.subbableProperties
  _this: @
  replaceProperty: true
  selectOnTop: true
  maxCount: 3
  callback: (e, value, strategy) =>
    @setState text:@textarea.text()
```

When I put the above function in componentDidMount, @props.account.subbableProperties is blank (hasn't yet loaded) so I can't put it there.

I tried using componentDidUpdate but for some reason this alert never triggers!

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) ->
 if !(_.isEqual(prevProps.account.subbableProperties, @props.account.subbableProperties))
     alert("they do differ!")
```

I also tried it in componentWillReceiveProps:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps: (newProps) ->
    console.log "newProps", newProps.account.subbableProperties
    console.log "newProps", newProps.account.subbableProperties.length
    console.log "props", @props.account.subbableProperties
    console.log "props", @props.account.subbableProperties.length

    if !(_.isEqual(newProps.account.subbableProperties, @props.account.subbableProperties))
      alert("it happens in willReceiveProps!")
```

It seems like newProps and @props update at the same time:
[image: Logs]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Triggering of `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentWillUpdate` is not a guarantee that the `nextProps` differ from the current props. It's absolutely ok if they are the same.

Comment: Should you be using `this.state` instead of `this.props`? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but the React guides recommend approaching props as if they are immutable, and instead recommend that you should be changing states.

Answer (score 0):

**componentDidUpdate** is triggered after you've a change in your component, this change comes from the DOM so will be triggered always when the component re-render himself.

I didn't understand much of what you saying because I don't know where `this.props` is coming but, did you tried `componentWillReceiveProps()`? This seems more properly because you're waiting for some props to be updated and not the whole component.

**EDIT:** Ok I just leave my message and saw you update your post.
So you did try `componentWillReceiveProps` already and give some more information. If you're waiting for some props or states to be changed probably you should try `componentWillUpdate` to see if they differ. I will check back later if you've some news :^).

Comment: Tried componentWillUpdate and am seeing similar behavior to componentWillReceiveProps. Somebody in the reactive slack channel suggested that both @props and nextProps (or prevProps) might be changing at once without a trigger because "I guess (and i might be wrong) that comonentWillReceiveProps triggers on shallow props changed, while you are changing the deeper tree rather than the shallow"